# ioexception when opening uri from external app

Tags: android, file, android-intent, uri, ioexception

From activity 1, I use an intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
i.setType("*/*"); 
try{
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Pick a file"), REQUEST_CODE_UPLOAD_FILE_FOR_IMPORT);
    }catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){
           Log.e("Error","FileManager not found!");
           }
```

and process the URI and extract data from the document. once I do so, I pass the extracted data and the URI to activity 2, where the user can see the data. the user also has the option of opening the original file from activity 2 and I do the following:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, getUri());
                PackageManager packageManager = activity.getPackageManager();
                List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
                if(isIntentSafe){
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
```

but whatever external app I choose gets an io Exception. how can I get them to open my document?

Comment: IOException usually means problems while loading file or resource. Your app can't read selected file for some reason. To identify the reason, it's required more information.

Comment: I let the user select documents, specifically spreadsheets. I have checks in place to check whether the file is a spreadsheet, and in my own app, it works fine. when I pass on the Uri to another app, that app shows an IO exception

Comment: Looks like second app does not have permissions to read the file

Comment: the files are in my internal storage, and I can open them separately in that app. This happens only when I pass on the Uri from my app

Comment: `the files are in my internal storage, and I can open them separately in that app`. You mean: my app got the permission and i can open it in the same app.

Comment: `This happens only when I pass on the Uri from my app `. ... and that other app tries to open the ur. Yes. That is normal. That other app does not have the permission.

Comment: Your own app wiil not even have the permission after restart. Save the uri before exiting and try to open the uri after restart and you will see.

Comment: so each Uri needs a separate permission? is it not enough for my 2nd app to have permission to access files?

Comment: how can I get a Uri I can share to another app?

Comment: You can try to add a flag on the intent. Use `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION );` Please report. If it does not work there is another solution.

Comment: I tried both `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` and `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` , neither is working

Comment: That is strange. Set both flags at the same time. It works for me. (I just checked it again). Try first in the same activity that got the permission.

Comment: Mmmmm setting the write flag is not advisible though. I get the strangest results depending on android version. As you only get a  limited time READ permission for an uri you cannot forward with WRITE permission.

Comment: I did. still not working. one of the apps asks me for SD card permission even though a. my file is in internal storage and b. i don't have an SD card

Answer (score 0):

Looks like second app does not have permissions to read the file.

For Reading spreadsheets Google have API for same.[API Details](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/worksheets#sheets_api_urls_visibilities_and_projections) or [Spreadsheet Service](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService) might help you.

Comment: i need to let the user select whatever app he chooses, the same as when user selects the file from a file browser, and the OS shows us a list of apps that can open the file

Comment: The reason for this can be URI what you are passing to intent. We can  have different uri due to OS version and devices.